# Magento 2 : Function's nesting level (8) exceeds 5 consider refactoring the function

Tags: magento2, php, coding-standards

I have check Coding standard of Module and i have get

[image: function nesting level]

this is my code

```
public function execute()
{
    $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead($this->directoryList::MEDIA);
    $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('cs/svg/');

    $storeManager = $this->storeManagerInterface;
    $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
    $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl($this->urlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($data['data'])) {
        $svgname = rand(10000, 99999);
        $path = $destinationPath.$svgname.".svg";
        $img = $data['data'];
        $this->fileForceContents($path, $img);
        return $mediaUrl.'cs/svg/'.$svgname.'.svg';
    }
    if (isset($data['itemId'])) {
        try {
            $cart = $this->cart;
            $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getId() == $data['itemId']) {
                    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
                    if (isset($options['info_buyRequest']['svg_data'])) {
                        $part = explode("/", $options['info_buyRequest']['svg_data']);
                        foreach ($part as $key => $value) {
                            if (strpos($value, '.svg') === true) {
                                $myFile = $destinationPath.$value;
                                if ($this->file->fileExists($myFile)) {
                                    $this->file->rm($myFile);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have 8 levels of foreach-if-try structures in your code.
Starting from `if (isset($data['itemId'])) {`  you have `if-try-foreach-if-if-foreach-if-if`.
You should keep this number below 5.

In your case you can simply do that by creating a new method in the class. Let's call it `processItem` with this code.

```
private function processItem($item) 
{
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
    if (isset($options['info_buyRequest']['svg_data'])) {
        $part = explode("/", $options['info_buyRequest']['svg_data']);
        foreach ($part as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($value, '.svg') === true) {
                $myFile = $destinationPath.$value;
                if ($this->file->fileExists($myFile)) {
                    $this->file->rm($myFile);
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Now your code can become

```
if (isset($data['itemId'])) {
    try {
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getId() == $data['itemId']) {
                $this->processItem($item);
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

you can also include `if ($item->getId() == $data['itemId']) {` in the new method but then you will have to pass `$data` as a parameter for this method.

Comment: one more level could be removed by inverting the first `if`

    if (!isset($data['itemId']))
        return false;
    try {
    ... 
    }

Comment: Instead `$cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()` this should work too `$item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($data['itemId'])` and then check if it is not `null`.

Comment: I agree...the code can be improved not just from complexity potin of view